# Excel help. Need to sutract only if value is > 0 to the next cell that has value > 0

Tags: excel, formula

I'm an excel novice so please excuse my ignorance. I've searched Google, I think I don't know what to look for. 
Column C values are represented as 0 or whole number.

C1   145

C2   0

C3   0

C4   142

C5   0

C6   0

C7   140

I'm trying to create a formula in D4 cell that would subtract C4 from the next value in column C that is not zero. Then also give the same calculation in D7 from the subtraction of C7 from the next cell that has a value greater than zero. Giving me D4 = 3 and D7 = 2 respectively. 
Is there a function that can give me this. There are many calculations on a whole spreadsheet and the values are not always in a certain cell depending on the values before.

Answer (score 0):

In D4 put:

```
=IF(C4<>0,INDEX($C$1:$C3,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:3)/($C$1:$C3<>0),1))-C4,"")
```

And copy down as far as needed.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Edit to fix typo in formula giving wrong answer.

Comment: I have 2 questions on your formula.  1)  Why aggregate instead of large?  is because it makes an array calculation within a regular formula?  or is it simply for potential errors in the data (ie the 6 option)?  2)  I do not understand the array portion of the aggregate formula `row($1:$3)/($C$1:$C3<>0)`.  I am not used to seeing a range divided by a range.  If this is a question on its own let me know I will post it as a stand alone Q.

Comment: 3rd question, is this only working due to the pattern of the numbers, ie, every third entry is the number?

Comment: I use the Aggregate() instead of Large(if()) just because it is not a CSE array formula.  The division part is what throws errors.  When the bottom array is false it is 0 and if you divide by 0 you get an error, thus the aggregate ignores it.  this would not matter the number of rows of 0's in the column.  It finds the largest row number with a number that is not 0 in the rows above the one that it is currently in.  If you look at `$C$1:$C3` the last number is 1 less than row 4 and it is relative, meaning as the formula is dragged down it will change to always be one less than the row number.

Comment: Sounds good, I had noticed the :$C3.  So if I understand this correctly, `Row($1:$3)` could have been replaced by any number such as 42 since you are just generating a divide by zero error for the information you are not interested in?

Comment: @ForwardEd nope that was a typo, thanks for catching it.  I changed it.

Comment: @ForwardEd I just realized my last number is wrong. I will update with a new photo when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Ok, so now I am confused again.  I broke out the `row($1:3)` and the `($C$1:$C3<>0)` and placed them in separate column and applied the CSE since they are supposed to be ARRAY formulas if I understand correctly. I extended the number table and applied the array formula to cover the range.  I was expecting to the column for the later equation to evaluate to true, false, false, true, etc.  Not what happened.  In Row 7, I got #N/A.  [see screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/STMzgYh.png?1)  So I am again confused as to the purpose of the ROW($1:3) part as it seems to blow up.